# Adding the addtion of two spark existing column to a datafarme

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to add the addition of two existing columns in spark data frame as a new column. I am doing as follow using Java API

```
sensorData2DoubleDF.withColumn("diff", sum(sensorData2DoubleDF.col("nodeid"),sensorData2DoubleDF.col("nodeid"));
```

but above code doesn't work, does anyone know how to do above?

Comment: does the below work?

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` is an aggregate function, you can simply use the `+` operator:

```
df.withColumn("sum", df.var1+df.var2)
```